# What exactly is this CompareAmounts function doing? (Analysis)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, function, analysis

I am analyzing a long JS code but I'm new to JS. Despite my best efforts, I have only been able to analyze around 85% of the code. This function CompareAmounts is still eluding me. This JS is supposed to run on a bank webpage, and I can't understand what this function is doing. Could anyone please point out the functionality to me?

```
function CompareAmounts(a, b) {
        var c = /^\-/gi;
        var d = "";
        var e = "";
        if (a.match(c)) {
            a = a.replace(c, "");
            a = a.replace(".", "");
            a = a.split(",");
            a[0] = (parseInt(a[0]) - parseInt(b)).toString();
            if (parseInt(a[0]) < 0) {
                a[0] = (a[0] * -1).toString();
            } else {
                d = "-";
                e = "";
            }
        } else {
            a = a.replace(".", "");
            a = a.split(",");
            a[0] = (parseInt(a[0]) + parseInt(b)).toString();
        }
        if (a[0].length > 3) {
            var f = a[0].substr(0, a[0].length - 3);
            var g = a[0].substr(a[0].length - 3, a[0].length);
            a[0] = f + "." + g;
        }
        a = d + a.toString() + e;
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried testing this code yourself with a number of different inputs?  I think stepping through the code using the JavaScript debugger in Chrome could prove very helpful.

Comment: That is the problem. This is part of an attack written for a German bank website that has been modified and I don't have access to it. So, I can't run the code on the website itself.

Comment: @MaxZoom - _"calumniating"_? Perhaps a and b should file a defamation suit! :-)

Comment: This code is calculating the difference or sum of `a` and `b`. It does not look like professional code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fairly convoluted way of adding one number to another number - `a + b`.

It contains extra logic to parse `a` as a European-style number in string form (remove all the `.`s, take the part before the `,` and then reconstruct the result in European number format afterward (incorrectly if the `a` or the result is greater than `999999`).

It does not have the same logic in place for parsing `b`, so I would presume that `b` is being passed in as a number value rather than a string.

```js
function CompareAmounts(a, b) {
  var c = /^\-/gi;
  var d = "";
  var e = "";
  if (a.match(c)) {
    a = a.replace(c, "");
    a = a.replace(".", "");
    a = a.split(",");
    a[0] = (parseInt(a[0]) - parseInt(b)).toString();
    if (parseInt(a[0]) < 0) {
      a[0] = (a[0] * -1).toString();
    } else {
      d = "-";
      e = "";
    }
  } else {
    a = a.replace(".", "");
    a = a.split(",");
    a[0] = (parseInt(a[0]) + parseInt(b)).toString();
  }
  if (a[0].length > 3) {
    var f = a[0].substr(0, a[0].length - 3);
    var g = a[0].substr(a[0].length - 3, a[0].length);
    a[0] = f + "." + g;
  }
  a = d + a.toString() + e;
  return a;
}

snippet.log(CompareAmounts("1.234,55", 12));
snippet.log(CompareAmounts("-10", 5));
snippet.log(CompareAmounts("50.400,80", 100));
snippet.log(CompareAmounts("1.000.000,00", 1));  // incorrect result
snippet.log(CompareAmounts("-50,80", 100));      // incorrect result
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: @MaxZoom It's calculating a sum, not a difference, and your last input is invalid, but yes, the result is wrong when `a` is a negative number with a fractional part, or when the numbers involved are over 1 miillion.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell me what use is this variable serving: "var c = /^\-/gi;"?

Comment: This removes negative sign if `a` is negative.

Comment: @intellikid It's a regex that matches a `-` at the beginning of a string (to check for negative numbers).